# CSS On hover show another element

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to use CSS to show `div id='b'` when I hover over `div id='a'`, but I cannot figure out how to do it because the `div 'a'` is inside another `div` that `div 'b'` is not in.

```
<div id='content'>
     <div id='a'>
         Hover me
     </div>
</div>
<div id='b'>
    Show me
</div>
```

Comment: no can do unless you 1) change your markup to have a nested/parent/ancestor relationship, 2) use javscript/jquery

Comment: Only way you could do this with CSS is if they were nested.

Comment: Thanks, just needed to confirm it.

Comment: @Jawad Borrowed that from another user's profile. Felt it was appropriate and necessary in today's world. =}

Comment: As we can know from the answers form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3552975), parent selector is not supported by all browsers(Firefox). I think a workaround is using JS.

Comment: Nota bene: if you're interested in making a feature hover-dependent, don't forget that some devices lack hover support (like some phones and tablets). If you're using CSS, you can check for hover support via the hover CSS media query. This will determine if the user's primary input mechanism can hover over elements. 

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

Answer (score 86):

we just can show same label div on hovering like this

```
<style>
#b {
    display: none;
}

#content:hover~#b{
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

Comment: TIL [This works](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) -  [If (and only if) `#b` is after `#content`](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/wrkxg/)

Comment: Precision : it also works if #b is not DIRECTLY after #content. This allows swapping. I'm baffled at how [CSS can sometimes eliminate the need of JQuery/Javascript for basic interactions](http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/2Lmgf7jr/1/).

Comment: @DACrosby in your fiddle, when `#b2` will display?

Comment: @Sajad with the noted HTML and only using CSS, it will never because [the sibling selectors cannot go backward hrough HTML, only forward](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/1265817). You'd need to put the `#content` before `#b2`, or use JavaScript, of use the `:hover` of an element earlier or higher up the DOM.

Answer (score 32):

It is indeed possible with the following code

```html
<div href="#" id='a'>
  Hover me
</div>
    
<div id='b'>
  Show me
</div>
```

and css

```css
#a {
  display: block;
}
    
#a:hover + #b {
  display:block;
}
    
#b {
  display:none;
}
```

Now by hovering on element #a shows element #b.

Answer (score 17):

You can use **axe** selectors for this.

There are two approaches:

## 1. Immediate Parent axe Selector (`<`)

```
#a:hover < #content + #b
```

This **axe** style rule will select `#b`, which is the immediate sibling of `#content`, which is the immediate parent of `#a` which has a `:hover` state.

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#content {
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#a, #b {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

#a {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
cursor: pointer;
}

#b {
display: none;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

#a:hover < #content + #b {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="a">Hover me</div>
</div>

<div id="b">Show me</div>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

---

## 2. Remote Element axe Selector (`\`)

```
#a:hover \ #b
```

This **axe** style rule will select `#b`, which is present in the same document as `#a` which has a `:hover` state.

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#content {
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#a, #b {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

#a {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
cursor: pointer;
}

#b {
display: none;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

#a:hover \ #b {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="a">Hover me</div>
</div>

<div id="b">Show me</div>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/RouninMedia/axe is that what this is? This isn't officially supported, but it's your project

Comment: Yes, it's a work in progress. A proof of concept, if you like.

Comment: This is the right answer because it shows the element only when `#b` is hovered, and not `#content` alone.

Comment: Great work you've got @Rounin. Your library greatly helped. I will study it more. I will also love to be a part of the continued success. If there's any way i can help; kindly let me know.

Comment: You're very kind, @Olamigoke Philip. It's currently about 33% finished (and, honestly, I've not really worked on it since Jan-Feb 2017). If all goes well, I plan to move _axe_ forward in 2021. Not least I want to significantly advance the _axeBlades_ extension.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), `+`, which matches the immediate next sibling.
Then classes might be used for multiple independent hovers:

```html
<div class='a'>
  Hover me 1
</div>
<div class='b'>
  Show me 1
</div>


<div class='a'>
  Hover me 2
</div>
<div class='b'>
  Show me 2
</div>
```

```css
.b {
  display: none;
}

.a:hover + .b {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is using position:absolute, you can run into issues with the approaches above.
Make sure you handle hover of the absolute element as well.

```html
<div class='content'>
  Hover me 1
</div>
<div class='hover'>
  Show me 1
</div>
```

```css
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content:hover + .hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.hover:hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```