# CSS Sibling Selector w/ Hover

Tags: html, css, selector, siblings

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I have two icons side by side, and underneath I have two spans that are hidden. When I mouse-over an icon I want the corresponding span to appear.

------------  HTML Part  -----------------

```
<span class="icons"><!--ICONS-->
    <li class="oneLI">one</li>
    <li class="twoLI">two</li>
</span>

<span class="popups">
    <span class="one"></span>
    <span class="two"></span>
</span>
```

--------------CSS Part --------------

```
span.popups span.one,span.popups span.two{opacity:0;

span.icons:first-child:hover + span.popups span.one{opacity:1}
span.icons:last-child:hover + span.popups span.two{opacity:1}
```

Now obviously this doesn't quite work, how would I go about this using only CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/RLhKK/

Comment: Basically, you can't, because you can't go "back up" the hierarchy. If you can't change the HTML for some reason, your best bet is JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicated topic [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749276/css-on-hover-show-another-element

Comment: The list structure above is invalid. List items must be children of a list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me explain your selector first which is

```
span.icons:first-child:hover + span.popups span.one{opacity:1}
```

Well, you are trying to select the *first-child* nested under `span.icons` and on hover of that you select `span.one` which is nested inside `span.popups` but you are going wrong here, you are selecting adjacent `span` element having `.popups` which is not adjacent to the `span` which is nested inside `.icons`, but in general, your selector is wrong, CSS cannot select the parent, inshort, CSS cannot go back once it enters an element, it cannot move up the hierarchy.

So you cannot do that way, either you need to alter your DOM, and bring all the `span` elements at the same level, or your hidden `span` should be at the child level.

And another way to achieve this is by using `position`, which I won't suggest here.

Also, your markup is invalid, you need to have `ul` element around `li`.

---

Lets alter the DOM and see how we can select

```
<span class="icons"><!-- Better use div here -->
    <ul>
        <li class="oneLI">one <br /><span class="one">Show Me</span></li>
        <li class="twoLI">two <br /><span class="two">Show me as well</span></li>
    </ul>
</span>

.icons li > span {
    opacity: 0;
}

.icons li:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/CBC8S/)

---

#### How would I've achieved this?

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/CBC8S/1/)

```
<div class="icons">
    <span class="hoverme">Hover Me</span>
    <div id="hover1">First</div>
    <span class="hoverme">Hover Me</span>
    <div id="hover2">Second</div>
</div>

.icons > div[id] {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.icons > span {
    display: block;
}

.icons > span:hover + div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

You can use `display` or `visibilty` property as well, if you do not want to use `opacity` as they are well suited when you want to transit an element using `transition`.

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/CBC8S/2/) *(Using `transition` if you are going for `opacity` method)*

Comment: @GolezTrol Patience patience :) am editing my answer

Comment: How would I do this if I want the "Hover Me's" side by side?

Answer (score 1):

You need the popups corresponding icons to be siblings.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qL8RU/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="icon1">one</a>
<span class="one">one</span>

<a href="#" class="icon2">two</a>    
<span class="two">two</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span.one, span.two {
    display:none;
}
a.icon1:hover + span.one {
    display:inline;
}
a.icon2:hover + span.two {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by putting the popups inside the icons. 
You can then address them using CSS, and position them somewhere else using absolute positioning:

CSS:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

li span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;
}

li:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="icons"><!--ICONS-->
    <li class="oneLI">one<span class="one">Popup for one.</span></li>
    <li class="twoLI">two<span class="two">Popup for one.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SK4Np/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to hide block you are hovering upon as I did you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-block">
  <div class="menu-block-inner">
    Menu (Hover me)
  </div>
  <div class="menu-expanded">
    <span><a href="#">Menu item1</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu item2</a></span>
  </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-block:hover .menu-block-inner{
    display: none;
}

.menu-block:hover .menu-expanded{
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-expanded {
    display: none;
}
```

The idea is to use parent div to trigger the hover event. After event is caught change child div's display/opacity/visibility, etc.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kbo2kugn/1/)