# Dropdown not displayed after hovering over an item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I learn front-end since few weeks but I cannot really figure out why my dropdown menu does not work.
My main menu looks like this:

```
<div id="main-container">

    <!-- Main navigation -->
    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="container">

                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="logo-wrapper pull-left">
                    <a href="index.html">Sit <span>On</span> Chair</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Main menu -->
                <nav class="nav-main pull-right">
                    <ul class="main-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown”>About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#”>Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#”>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#”>News</a>
                        <a href="#”>Our team</a>
                        <a href="#”>History</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

and css file looks like this:

```
/* Text styles */
body {
    font-family: 'ralewayregular';
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ralewayregular';
    src: url('../fonts/raleway-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/raleway-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/raleway-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/raleway-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/raleway-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/raleway-regular.svg#ralewayregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1, h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main content */
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

/* Container styles */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}

/* Main header */
.main-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* Logo */
.logo-wrapper {
    margin: 16px 0;
}

/* General header styles */
.header-content .main-nav-list li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 30px;
    &:nth-child(3) {
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}

.header-content {
    span {
        color: #66dfc9;
        transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    a {
        color: #ffffff;
        transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        &:hover {
            color: #66dfc9;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
            span {
                color: #ffffff;
                transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Dropdown */
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 230px;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #000000;
    a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        &:hover {
            color: #66dfc9;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

I would like to display .dropdown-content when hovering over 'About us’ link.
Is it possible to display div element if it is outside of an unordered list?
Everything works fine except the last part of my code.

I have tried to change my unordered list for div element, display div element inside link About us, but it also does not work.

Comment: Beware you have in your HTML code some errors. You have `”` instead `"`

Comment: Wow, good catch Luis - I didn't even see that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749276/css-on-hover-show-another-element

Comment: @Luis P. A. Good catch. I did not notice that in my text editor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the onmouseover event. I did something like this and it works fine.

```
<li><a href="#" class= "dropdown" onmouseover = "document.getElementById('disp').style.display = 'block';">About us</a></li>

<div class="dropdown-content" id = "disp" style="display:none;">
```

1) set display to *none* for the div which you want it to appear when the user hovers his mouse

2) for the 'about us' link, add the event 'onmouseover' and set the div display to 'block'.

Comment: It also works correctly. I just have to add event for closing dropdown i.e. when clicked anywhere outside of the dropdown, because in this case dropdown is displayed until page is refreshed/reloaded but i know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use javascript, the following code works:

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Main menu -->
            <nav class="nav-main pull-right">
                <ul class="main-nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">About us</a>
                     <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">News</a>
                    <a href="#">Our team</a>
                    <a href="#">History</a>
                </div></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
```

you have to move .dropdown-content under the .dropdown a tag
then you select it using:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/ff0u7omy/)

Comment: I tried by myself to move .dropdown-content under the .dropdown tag but selector .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content did not work. Thank you for help.

Comment: you have to use the + selector to make this work @Kamil

Comment: otherwise the rule .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content looks for a descentant of .dropdown called  .dropdown-content which does not exists

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not use + selector and that was my little mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code tested in local:

```
<style type="text/css">
            ul{
                background: gray;
            }
            ul>li{
                padding: 10px 15px;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: Arial;
                display: inline-block;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            ul li.dropdown{
                position: relative;
            }
            .dropdown-list{
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                width: 80px;
            }
            ul li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-list{
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li class="dropdown">About
                <ul class="dropdown-list">
                    <li>Item-1</li>
                    <li>Item-2</li>
                    <li>Item-3</li>
                    <li>Item-4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I do not even need to check it in local because I see it will work :) It is classic dropdown menu using unordered list and list items. I wondered if it possible to create it using ul, li and div tags. Anyway thanks for help