# Hovering not working while displaying an element on hovering another button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

## Intro

I am having a color palette. I wanted to display a tooltip whenever I hover that button. But when I hover over them , it is not.

I am using ReactJS and css for styling.

So this is the color palette and I want to display the tooltip whenver someone hovers any button.

[image: cp]

Now I followed upto 2nd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749276/css-on-hover-show-another-element). But it is not working.

## Code

**App.js**

```
themeList.map((t, k) => (
      <button
        key={k}
        id="theme_color_btn"
        data-theme={t}
        onKeyDown={this.keyboardNavigation}
        className={`theme-button bg-${t}-500${theme === t ? " is-active" : ""}`}
        onClick={this.changeTheme}
      >
        <div
          id="tooltip"
          className={`bg-${t}-100 absolute text-${t}-900 text-sm p-1 rounded-md ring-1 ring-purple-900 z-10 mt-3 transition-transform capitalize `}
        >
          {t}
        </div>
      </button>
```

where `const themeList = [ "indigo", "yellow", "red", "purple", "pink", "blue", "green", ];`
**index.css**

```
#theme_color_btn{
  display:block;
}

#theme_color_btn:hover + #tooltip{
  display:block; 
  z-index:5;
  background-color:gray;
}

#tooltip {
  display:none ;
}
```

Instead,no tooltips are displaying on hover.

For Full code refer **index.css** and **App.js** files **[here](https://github.com/mohitm15/tailblocks/tree/master/src)**

Comment: `+` is the adjacent _sibling_ combinator. But `#theme_color_btn` and `#tooltip` _are not_ siblings in the HTML structure you have shown. The tooltip is a _descendant_ of the button, so you want `#theme_color_btn:hover #tooltip`

Comment: Whoa....whoa....whoa... Thank you so so so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the plus

```
#theme_color_btn:hover #tooltip{
   display:block; 
   z-index:5;
   background-color:gray;
 }
```

Hope this works

Comment: I already got answer from first comment.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `#theme_color_btn:hover + #tooltip` but the + operator is used for "the next element" but #tooltip is inside #theme_color_btn ...

So you should write something like

`#theme_color_btn:hover #tooltip`

or

`#theme_color_btn:hover > #tooltip`

Look here: [Css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I already got answer from first comment.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Use this css structure. This will work for sure

```
#theme_color_btn:hover{
&#tooltip{
  display:block; 
  z-index:5;
  background-color:gray;
}
}

#tooltip {
  display:none ;
}
```

Comment: I already got answer from first comment.Thank you !